# derivability don't imply partial to be continuous ? example

Tags: derivatives, continuity, partial-derivative

Is $$f(x,y) =\begin{cases} x^2+2x+2y & \text{ for } (x,y)\neq (0,0) \\ y^2  & \text{ for } (x,y)=(0,0) \end{cases}$$ derivable? But its partials are not continuous?

Comment: The function you have defined is the same as the polynomial $f(x,y)=x^2+2x+2y$, so it is differentiable everywhere in $R^2$ and has continuous partial derivatives everywhere also.

Comment: It's not even true in one dimension that a differentiable function $f$ must have $f'$ continuous. (Take $f(x) = x^2 \sin 1/x$, for example.) Are you alluding to the result that the existence and continuity of partial derivatives implies differentiability?

Comment: No the opposite differentiability don't imply that the parcials derivatives are continuous however they exist @anomaly

Comment: Is that true? @anomaly

Comment: Right: A differentiable (as opposed to $C^1$) function may have partial derivatives that are not continuous. In one dimension, take $f(x) = x^2 \sin 1/x$; in multiple dimensions, take something like $r^2 \sin 1/r$ for $r^2 = x_1^2 + \cdots + x_n^2$.

Comment: What about having parcials but not being differentiable @anomaly

Comment: Sure. Take something like $x^2 y/ (x^2 + y^2)$ at $(x, y) = (0, 0)$.

Comment: @anomaly but in that case x^2y/(x^2+y^2) at(x,y)=(0,0)is not define and like was told you can notsay about partials here and clear ithas partials.butin sameway you can not talk about partials in this point can you not talk about differentiability here?but clearly on(0,0)f is  continuous.makes since talk about being derivable or full derivable(don'tmake confusion with total derivable) and for(0,0)it is said it doesn't belong to the domain of derivaity of f function.like in singlevariable function wheref(x) if it was justonepoint where is derivale it is derivable howevernot continuouslyderivable

Comment: @studentNk Sorry, I can't read your comment. I don't know what you mean, but the function I gave is continuous at $(0, 0)$.

Comment: @anomaly yes I realize that now ,your function is define for (x,y)=(0,0).Thus i am not sure how I prove is not diferentiable ,what to use to see is not diferentiable?can you give a hint?

Answer (score 2):

If a function $f(x,y)$ is continuous at a point in its domain and its partial derivatives exist at that point, then $f(x,y)$ is said to be derivable at that point.

Here, $f(x,y)$ is continuous at $(0,0)$.

And if both $f^\prime_x$ and $f^\prime_y$ exist at $(0,0)$, then $f(x,y)$ is derivable at $(0,0)$.

So, $f^\prime_x =\lim_{h \to 0}$ $\frac{f(h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}$

Hence, $f^\prime_x = 2$

Similarly, $f^\prime_y =\lim_{h \to 0}$ $\frac{f(0,h)-f(0,0)}{h}$

Hence, $f^\prime_y = 2$

So, $f(x,y)$ is derivable at $(0,0)$.

And at all points in $R^2$,except $(0,0)$, it's pretty obvious that $f(x,y)$ is derivable as $f(x,y)$ is simply a polynomial in that domain.

Hence, $f(x,y)$ is derivable on $R^2$.

Comment: But when (x,y)=(0,0) f(x,y)=y^2 and f`y(x,y)=2y hence f`y(0,0)=0 $\neq$ 2 and f`x(0,0)=0 $\neq$2 @user3679857

Comment: You can't write $f^\prime_y = 2y$ before actually proving that $f(x,y)$ is derivable on that $(0,0)$.

Comment: First you prove $f(x,y)$ is derivable and then you use the results based on differentiation.

Comment: If its not derivable then its parcials don't exist ?@user3679857

Comment: The fact that the partial derivetives exist does not suffice to say that the function it's differentiable there. They have to be continuos as well

Comment: So if the partials exist and the function is continuous then it can be said that a function is derivable however its partials can be not continuous? @Ant

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function#Differentiability_in_higher_dimensions Even if the partial exist and the functino is continuos, you have no guarantee that the function is differentiable. You have to require the partial derivatives continuous as well @studentNk

Comment: how to see the partial derivatives are continuous ? @Ant

Comment: @studentNk you have to calculate them. Then it's only a matter of seeing if a function is continuos, and I think you know how to do that

Comment: @Ant but what happens when you have a function like$$g(x,y) =\begin{cases} x^2+2x+3y+10 & \text{ for } (x,y)= (0,0) \\ y^2+3y+2x+5  & \text{ for } (x,y)\neq (0,0) \end{cases}$$ clearly the 2 partial derivatives of the 2 branches are equal on (0,0) (2 and 2 for partial x,and 3 and 3 for partial y) where could be discontinuous but isn't however on (0,0) f is discontinuous 10 and 5. So how it can be partials continuous imply derivability imply f be continuous but isn't .what is wrong here?

Comment: @studentNk First of all, you can just write $g(x,y) = 10$ if $(x,y) = (0, 0)$, there is no point in writing that way. This way you can also see that is pointless in differentiating $x^2 + 2x + 3y + 10$ with the usual rules, as it is only valid in one point and derivatives deal with neighbourhoods. Finally, the "contradiction" is explained by remembering that the usual rules for differentiating only make sense if the derivative is defined, and if the function is not continuos they are not defined.

Comment: Thank you for last comment.how do we check derivibality with a function like $f(x,y)=\frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2} $ because if I plug (0,0) for the partials is undefined and hence I can not put them on the definition of differential limit.or this why is not diferentiable? @Ant

Comment: @Ant I am going to answer my own comment ,if a function is continuous at point but the partials are discontinuous at that point then is not derivable at that point.is this true?